# commuication between salve and framework scheduler in Mesos

Tags: mesos

In Mesos, the framework gets notified about the task's completion or failure. I think this message should be sent from the slave. What I am curious is the slave sends this message directly to the framework or it asks the master to forward this message? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Mesos Agents communicate only with Mesos Master who is responsible to forward information to scheduler.

Comment: @janisz Many thanks for your reply. I am sorry to bother you but I just want to make sure I am on the right track. When I call the executor driver's `sendStatusUpdate` [API](http://mesos.apache.org/api/latest/java/org/apache/mesos/MesosExecutorDriver.html) to inform the the scheduler of the task finishing update, the messages's flowing path is: Executor->Slave->Master->Scheduler, am I right? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct!